# I want to modify a list of tuples defined outside a function in order to change the bool value only

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, tuples

Here is my code snippet

```
messages = [('food', False), ('water', False), ('sleep', False)]


def bool_changer(list_):
    for idx, word in enumerate(list_):
        # change tuple to list
        word = list(word)
        # print(word)
        if not word[1]:
            # change False to True
            word[1] = True
            # back to tuple
            word = tuple(word)
            print(word)
    return list_


print(bool_changer(messages))  # still prints the initial, no change applied
print(messages)  # still prints the initial ie [('food', False), ('water', False), ('sleep', False)]

# Desired output --> messages = [('food', True), ('water', True), ('sleep', True)]
```

Is there anything I need to change? coz I thought changing the inner tuples to lists would help me but in vain. Any other method is welcome btw

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually changing the list, just the local `word` variable. Try

```
def bool_changer(list_):
    for i in range(len(list_)):
        if not list_[i][1]:
            list_[i] = (list_[i][0], True)
            print(list_[i])
    return list_

print(bool_changer(messages)) # [('food', True), ('water', True), ('sleep', True)]
print(messages) # [('food', True), ('water', True), ('sleep', True)]
```